# Which encoding replaces 'é' by '\351'?

Tags: character-encoding

I'm trying to create pdf from fdf file but I have problem with some UTF-8 characters. I would like to replace them but I don't know which encoding to find. Which encoding can replace UTF-8 characters:

- é by \351
- č by \226

Thank you for all answers.

Comment: `\351` looks like [OctalEscape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) for é _Latin Small Letter E With Acute_ (`\u00E9`). Unfortunately, `\226` isn't the case as č _Latin Small Letter C With Caron_ is `\u010D` which exceeds octal escape range…

Comment: @JosefZ, and what encoding is \u00E9 and also \u010D? Can I use it in string instead of é or č character?

Comment: The encoding is **ISO-8859-1**. I speak Spanish and also I was surprised: if you copy-paste \351 in your browser it will show you "é" (try \363 for ó). It converts te scape literals into their corresponding _letter_ for **Strings in Java** which uses this encoding. See the following table for whole reference: [ISO-8859-1 (ISO Latin 1) Character Encoding](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~stolfi/EXPORT/www/ISO-8859-1-Encoding.html)